# How should I test vue components when using Firebase?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, firebase, vue.js, vue-test-utils

I'm writing unit tests for a vue project that uses firebase. The tests are using vue-test-utils.

The thing is I'm having trouble trying to bypass the auth, and with every test I find myself doing something like this.

```
...
const login = async () => {
return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).then(
    res => {
        return res
    },
    err => {
        return new Error(err)
    })
}
...
describe('some component', () => {
    it('test something', async () => {
        try {
            await login()
            ...
        } catch (e) {
            ...
        }
    })
    it('test something else', async () => {
        try {
            await login()
            ...
        } catch (e) {
            ...
        }
    })
})
```

My question is. What is the recommended way to test vue components that use firebase and how to avoid having to login for every test?

Hope I explained my question correctly!

I ended up doing this, as in my case it's enough to do it once.

```
...
beforeAll(() => {
  return login()
})

describe('some component', ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use a beforeEach function in your test suite to get authenticated/check if authentication is still valid, simply:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    try {
        await login()
        ...
    } catch (e) {
        ...
    }
})
```

However, are you doing this logic directly in a vue component? You ideally don't want to make these kind of calls directly from your vue components. If you move that logic out of your component and into a service class (or go a step further and use vuex to manage your state etc..), then you can test the firebase logic separately from your component logic.

Comment: Thanks! That's much less repetitive. But no, I do all the firebase logic inside the components. Do you have a reference of a project or a blog post that separates this logic?

Comment: A quick google pulled up this - https://medium.com/@amenallah.hsoumi/building-a-progressive-quiz-app-with-vue-vuex-and-firestore-part-2-a586516eeabe . You'll see they have the login action that actually makes the firebase call in 'actions' . Hope it helps!